# Which of the following would be the correct word use?

Tags: difference, past-participles

Which sentence would be correct? Discussion around the possibility of them both being correct?

> The washer is broke.

OR

> The washer is broken.

Comment: People do say "the washer is broke" but it is ungrammatical.

Comment: You can also say it in the active form: The washer broke.

Answer (score 1):

Of course "The washer is broken."
Because in the passive voice you should use past participle.

Answer (score 1):

> The washer is broke.

It means there is a person who works as a washer and [they have no money (2)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/broke).

> The washer is broken.

It means the (washing) machine [doesn't function properly (37)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break).